# Why i am getting 400 Bad Request error when sending json data in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I am trying to write a small restful api application, i am using `Chrome Postman` extension for sending requests to the app .

I believe that my code does not have mistakes but every time i am sending post request a **400 Bad Request** error raising , here is my code:

```
@api_route.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    return jsonify({'message':'Api v1.0'})

@api_route.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    data = request.get_json()
    if data:
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256')
        api = Api(email=data['email'], password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(api)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message', 'New User Created!'})
```

The json data that i am sending looks like this:

`{"email" : "Test", "password" : "123123123"}`

Why i am getting the **400 error** ??

**Update**:

Screenshots for the requests using Postman:

**GET Request**
[image: GET Request]

**POST Request**
[image: POST Request]

Here i am initiating api route inside api controller :

```
from flask import Blueprint
api_route = Blueprint(
    'api',
    __name__
)
from . import views
```

then i am registering it inside `def create_app()` function :

```
from .api import api_route
app.register_blueprint(api_route)
```

Here are the extensions that i am using in my application:

```
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension()
assets_env = Environment()
cache = Cache()
moment = Moment()
htmlminify = HTMLMIN()
csrf = CSRFProtect()
jac = JAC()
googlemap = GoogleMaps()
session = Session()
principal = Principal()
```

Comment: What's the route to your request?

Comment: @MrPyCharm, http://localhost:5000/api

Comment: Can you replace `return jsonify({'message', 'New User Created!'})` with `return jsonify({'message': 'New User Created!'})`and give it a try?

Comment: I tried , the same error raising , even i just tried to print out the data and removed the return function !!

Comment: Well, 400 means there's some issue with the request you're trying to make. Is a `GET` request at `localhost:5000/api` working?

Comment: @MrPyCharm, yes, the GET request working perfect it returns the message !

Comment: The route is correct , i also tried to change the route to something like `/api/post` but without avail !

Comment: Try returning something after `if ` statement as a view in Flask needs to return something.

Comment: @MrPyCharm, same thing !!, this one i just sent a POST request to the same function but without fetching any data its just `if request.method == POST: return jsonify({ 'message' : 'Hello from API!' })`

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach would be to structure your views as follows:

Instead of creating view with same route for different request methods, you can handle the request methods in the same view:

```
@api_route.route('/api', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify({'message':'Api v1.0'})

    else:
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if data:
            hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256')
            api = Api(email=data['email'], password=hashed_password)
            db.session.add(api)
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'message': 'New User Created!'})

        # Just in case the if condition didn't satisfy
        return None
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your interest dude, but nothing changed the error still raising up , i am really confused why that won't work ??, i typed another small api todo list months ago and the code looks the same nothing changed except the routes names !

Comment: Well, the above snippet is working fine on my system. You might also check the `Api` call you are making, that could be causing the issue

Comment: If the Api object causing the problem so it should return error that says for example something happened while data inserted into database , but here the error showing up immediately if i send POST request !!

Comment: Does the data gets inserted into db?

Comment: Are there some flask extensions that causing this kind of problem ?? , or maybe the configuration ?? , in my app i have another 4 blueprints route registered to blueprint including the `api_route` !!!

Comment: No nothing get inserted at all !!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post some more source code, or a screenshot of the request you're making.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem, i've initiated `CSRFProtect` with app so i need to include `X-CSRFToken` in all my requests, so i have two choices:

1 - To include the csrf_token in `request.headers` for all the requests

2 - Using `@csrf.exempt` decorator that coming with `flask_wtf.csrf`

For now i am using `@csrf.exempt`, so it become like this:

```
@api_route.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def create_user():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify({'message' : 'API v1.0'})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256')
        new_user_api = Api(email=data['email'], password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user_api)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message' : 'New user created!'})
    return return jsonify({'message' : 'No user has been added!'})
```

Thanks for @MrPyCharm for his interests , salute :) .

Answer (score 0):

A note for anyone else experiencing this with PostMan and Flask - you will also hit a HTTP 404 if your URL in PostMan is HTTPS but your Flask app only handles HTTP.